# MSBuild: Exec command through files in each directory

Tags: msbuild

I have a CLI tool to read a text file and generate an output text file.

```
MyTool.exe inputFile1.txt inputFile2.txt inputFileN.txt -o outputFile.txt
```

Then I have a directory hierarchy as below

```
MainDir
    SubDir1
        File1
        File2
    SubDir2
        File3
        File4
    SubDirN
        FileN
```

I would like to create a MSBuild project file for another project. Inside this msbuildproj file, I need to execute MyTool.exe for all files in each sub directory and create one output file for each sub directory.

```
MyTool.exe MainDir\SubDir1\File1 MainDir\SubDir1\File2 -o outputFile1.txt
MyTool.exe MainDir\SubDir2\File3 MainDir\SubDir1\File4 -o outputFile2.txt
MyTool.exe MainDir\SubDirN\FileN -o outputFileN.txt
```

How to make a loop in MSBuild script to do it?

Comment: Are SubDir1, SubDir2.. SubDirN known and static or dynamic?

Comment: Those files are created after building a visual studio solution.
So they are dynamic.